# Delete dynamic variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I want to know how do can free memory used by dynamic variables.
For eg,

```
function func1(name){
  this.name = name;
}
func1.prototype.method1 = function(){
  console.log(this.name);
}

// initializing dynamic variable dyVar
let dyVar = new func1("Variable1");
dyVar.method1();

// now change dyVar, here I want to free up the memory
//so that I won't have any trace of "Variable1" and re-initialize dyVar
dyVar = new func1("Var2");
```

To do this do I need to use delete before renitialize?

```
//something like this
delete dyVar
dyVar = new func1("Var2");
```

If there's something which you think you might share, please do share

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? `dyVar` is just a normal variable. It's only "dynamic" because it can be reassigned. You can assign it to `null` or anything else to make the object eligible for garbage collection but that doesn't *necessarily* free the memory right now. It might also *not* free the memory if you have other references to the object. Reassigning to *any other value* would have the exact same effect as reassigning to `null`. What issue do you face that makes you think you need to do anything special?

Comment: You mean if I reassign it to null before reassigning to some other value, it would be same as just reassigning it to some other value?

Comment: Yes. Reassigning to *anything* removes the reference to the previous object.

Comment: And how much time does garbage collection take to free up the memory?

Comment: Some amount of time. It normally shouldn't matter. The fact that you ask makes me suspicious you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Okay. Just leaning JS, so I'm playing around it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To do this do I need to use delete before renitialize?

No.

Objects get marked for garbage collection when no references to them remain.

`dyVar = new func1("Var2");` overwrites the only reference you have to the previous object so it gets marked for garbage collection just by doing that.

(And `delete` only works on properties of objects, not on variables)

Comment: garbage collection does not free the memory instantaneously, right? Is there a way to I can free the memory instantly?

Comment: @kapilsarwat Why? Are you solving [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: Actually I'm new to JS, so it might help me to learn. Right now, I'm not designing a system or working on a project so bothering about the XY rpoblem is not a concern.

Comment: @kapilsarwat then you don't have a problem. We want practical and solvable problems here. Extremely broad questions are not helpful as solutions are often strongly related to specifics.